# CMD command to check whether the internet connection has already started

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I know that `netsh wlan start hostednetwork` can turn the hotspot on, and `netsh wlan stop hostednetwork` truns it off.

When the hotspot has already started and I type `netsh wlan start hostednetwork`, its output shows `the hosted network started`

But how can I check whether the internet connection has already started? `if statment` in CMD? or writing a `.bat` file?

for example:

```
if(hostednetwork==started){
netsh wlan stop hostednetwork;
}else{
netsh wlan start hostednetwork;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't anderstand the finality of you code :

"If is connected then disconnect and If not connect"

But here is a solution :

```
@echo off&cls
ping -n 1 google.com
if %errorlevel% Equ 0 netsh wlan stop hostednetwork
if %errorlevel% Equ 1 netsh wlan start hostednetwork
```

If you want to check if you already have en Cable Ethernet connexion, first disable the WLAN connexion ant then make the `Ping` test. If you don't have any connexion then you start your WLAN again.

```
@echo off&cls
netsh wlan stop hostednetwork
ping -n 1 google.com
if %errorlevel% Equ 1 netsh wlan start hostednetwork
```

Comment: Yes, that's literally what it means "If is connected then disconnect and If not connect". So I could just double click on the .bat file to connect and disconnect.

Comment: but ping will not work here because i'm already connected to internet with my Ethernet cable. instead, i need to check whether the hostednetwork has been started

Comment: OK ! you already connected with you Ethernet cable. Then you are trying to check if your ethernet connexion is OK. IF OK you want to disable the WLAN connexion if not you want to activate your WLAN conexion. Then first disable your WLAN connexion and check with a ping if you already have a conexion if yes, everithing OK if not you satrt your WLAN again. Check the EDIT